# Problem populating a Jlist based on two Jcomboboxes connected to a PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist

Good afternoon

I'm working on a project in witch I have to calculate the performance of a pump for certain parameters like rotation, number of stages, diameter and viscosity. At first I created a database using PostgreSQL with several commercial pumps. The database contains schemas as the companies that manufacture the pumps, in each schema there are tables representing the different series of pumps and the tables have several pumps organized as lines. The lines contains coefficients that represent the pumps and that are necessary to calculate the performance.

I tried to code the application in C++, but was too hard to connect with Postgre, so I ended working with Java and Netbeans (I think it's easier to newcomers). The application is running quite good so far, but I have found two problems that I cannot solve.

To select the pump to make the calculations I had to use two Jcomboboxes and a Jlist. The first Jcombobox is for selecting the manufacturer, the second to select the serie. Finally, the Jlist displays all the pumps in that serie so the user can select one.

I was able to populate the first Jcombobox with the schemas of the database (thanks to you guys, actually), the second with the tables of the schema selected in the first and the Jlist with the names of the pumps.

The first problem is that I cannot clear the second Jcombobox (the series one) after changing the selected manufacturer in the first Jcombobox, it will add more itens every time that I change the first Jcombobox, even if I re-select an item that was already selected. I tried using the command  "removeAllItems()", but then it displays just one table and stop filling the Jcombobox.

The second problem is that, when I select a serie in the second Jcombobox, it doesn't immediately display the pumps in the Jlist, the Jlist starts displaing after I select another serie. So, I have to select one and then change to another so the pumps start appearing in the Jlist.

I'm sorry for the long text and the english errors, I hope its enough for you guys to understand. I know the code is not pretty, that's because I'm not so good at this yet and I'm in a bit of a hurry to deliver it.

Here is the code, without all the generated code that Netbeans does.

```
public final class LabPump extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

public LabPump() {
    initComponents();

    con = ConnectPump.connect();

    FillSelectFabricante();

}

public void FillSelectFabricante(){

    try {
        rs = con.getMetaData().getSchemas();

        while(rs.next()){
            String schemas = rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM");

            if(schemas.equals("information_schema") || schemas.equals("pg_catalog")){
            }
            else{
                selectFabricante.addItem(schemas);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,error);
    }

}

public void FillSelectSerie(String fabricante){

    //selectSerie.removeAllItems();

    try {
        String[] sql = {"TABLE"};
        rs = con.getMetaData().getTables(null, fabricante, "%", sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            String tables = rs.getString(3);

            selectSerie.addItem(tables);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,error);
    }

}

public void FillListBomba(String fabricante, String serie){

    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    dlm.removeAllElements();

    try{
        String sql = "select * from " + fabricante + "." + serie;
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String bomba = rs.getString("bomba");
            dlm.addElement(bomba);
        }
    listBomba.setModel(dlm);
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,error);
    } 

}

    private void selectSerieActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    selectSerie.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        String fabricante = selectFabricante.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String serie = selectSerie.getSelectedItem().toString();

        FillListBomba(fabricante, serie);

    });
}                                           

private void selectFabricanteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

    String fabricante = selectFabricante.getSelectedItem().toString();

    FillSelectSerie(fabricante);

}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: I notice in `selectSerieActionPerformed` the action you have is to add another action listener to `selectSerie` That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: You know, I put it there after seeing another post and after that the Jlist started working, but now I removed it and the second problem I listed here stopped happening. That helped! Thank you very much. Now there's just the problem of cleaning the second combobox.

Comment: The second combobox is the one you called 'selectSerie', isn't it? I can't see why it wouldn't work (assuming you uncommented the selectSerie.removeAllItems(); line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem just now. When the `selectSerie.removeAllItems()` line was uncommented the program returned a `NullPointerException` error.

To solve the problem I used the `DefaultComboBoxModel` class and then used the `RemoveAllElements()` method. I'm not quite sure why the other method didn't work though.

Thanks for your time and help [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231929/peter-hull).

```
public void FillSelectSerie(String fabricante) {

    DefaultComboBoxModel box;
    box = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    box.removeAllElements();

    try {
        String[] sql = {"TABLE"};
        rs = con.getMetaData().getTables(null, fabricante, "%", sql);
        box.addElement("-");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String tables = rs.getString(3);
            box.addElement(tables);
        }
        selectSerie.setModel(box);
    } catch (SQLException error) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,error);
    }
}
```